# Feature based grammar to generate output in nltk

Tags: nltk

For generating the code back following code doesn't work:

```
S[SEM=(?dk + ?ak)] -> DK[SEM=?dk] AK[SEM=?ak]
AK[SEM=''] -> '@'
DK[SEM='DECLARE'] -> 'DECLARE'
```

But the following code works:

```
S[SEM=?dk] -> DK[SEM=?dk] AK
AK -> '@'
DK[SEM='DECLARE'] -> 'DECLARE'
```

Any ideas on how can i make it work?

Comment: what's that? you need to give some reference to the nltk package or at least explain what's that. If i'm not wrong you're using `nltk.sem` logic parser?

Comment: from nltk import load_parser
 cp = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/sql0.fcfg')
 query = 'What cities are located in China'
 trees = list(cp.parse(query.split()))
 answer = trees[0].label()['SEM']
 answer = [s for s in answer if s]
 q = ' '.join(answer)
 print(q)-->i got this code in nltk book...which will automatically use SEM to generate something

Comment: Can you tell me after parsing how can we generate the target language using nltk?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I have to give following line in the starting of grammar

```
%Start S
```